# Edit the response after a redirect (node.js & express)

Tags: node.js, express

I have a Nodejs express app which receives POST requests (XML) and simply redirects them to a different host replying to the original caller (also with an XML message).

```
var app = require('express')();

app.post('/', function(req, res) {
  res.redirect(307, 'http://localhost:8888/');
});

app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log('Application listening on http://localhost:3000/');
});
```

What I am trying to achieve is to modify the response from the second host (localhost:8888). How do I intercept and edit the response from the second host before it reaches the original caller?

I cannot figure it out from the documentation so any help would be very appreciated, thank you.

Comment: What is the `response`?

Comment: I would suggest you to use: https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-interceptor

Comment: @hoangdv a standard soap xml message, where I'd like an attribute like: `<m:Number>25</m:Number>`  to be changed to `<m:Number>30</m:Number>`. But my struggle is how do I access that message from the second host. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do that as the response from server 2 is fetched by the client handling the redirect (e.g. your browser). You have to fetch the response yourself in the server side, modify it and send it back.

```
var app = require('express')();
var request = // your preferred http library

app.post('/', function(req, res) {
  request.get('http://localhost:8888/', function (err, response) {
    if (err) {
      return res.error(err);
    }

    // Here you have the response, you can modify it.

    res.send(response.body);
  });
});

app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log('Application listening on http://localhost:3000/');
});
```